# How can i fetch firebase collection document details using provider in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch firebase document details of a particular document to a list and then use that list in different pages or widget as required.

This is what i have tried... I made one page name Firebasestream where i am mapping the document details to a list

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:second_app/Cart.dart';

class Firebasestream  {

  final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  Stream<List<Cart>> getbooks() {
    return _firestore.collection("users").document("+919954603381").collection("cart").snapshots().map((event) => event.documents
        .map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot)
    => Cart(description: documentSnapshot.data["description"]))
        .toList());

}}
```

Then i have created the model class name Cart where the list is mapped.

```
class Cart{

String description;


Cart({this.description});
}
```

This is my main class

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:second_app/Cart.dart';
import 'package:second_app/Firebasestream.dart';
import 'package:second_app/Kaku.dart';


void main() => runApp((MyApp()));




class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {


    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }




  //

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Firebasestream fs = Firebasestream();

    return StreamProvider(
      create:(BuildContext context)=> fs.getbooks(),
      child: Kaku(),
    );

  }
}



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:second_app/Cart.dart';

class Kaku extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var list = Provider.of<List<Cart>>(context);
    print(list.length.toString());
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Hii"),
        ),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But the list which i am getting is empty.. I tried to print the length of the list but it showing 0 whereas in firebase there are 3 documents

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your collections/subcollections/documents structures?

Comment: I have attached

Comment: Thank you, I don't see how is related the users collections with the cart collection, can you explain and if possible attach another screenshot with said collection?